# How to make a rectangle move with multiple direction keys at once?

Tags: java

Hi this may be very stupid, but please try to understand that I am an absolute beginner at Java programming. I have been trying to learn it on my own from the internet.

I was trying to make a simple Applet that can move a square using the KeyListener.

First I made a version that can only detect one key at a time. So I looked up a tutorial on YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UaEUrbpDPE). It used an ArrayList to somehow handle the issue with what was referred to as "Ghosting". The tutorial showed flawless results but my code resulted in some weird problems:

Initially the square moved smoothly in any direction for some time. The square could mainly be moved down and right. After pressing up or left a few times the square could no longer be moved!!!

Can anyone please guide me on what I am doing wrong or how else this could have been accomplished?

Here is the code that I began with (One button at a time detection):

```
package boxHero;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class boxGame extends Applet implements KeyListener {

private Rectangle rect;                          
private int x = 20, y = 20, recW = 50, recH = 50;


public void init() {
    setSize(600, 500);                           
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    this.addKeyListener(this);

    rect = new Rectangle (x, y, recW, recH);     
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g2.fill(rect);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // Can't detect more than one key at a time
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        rect.setLocation(rect.x + 10, rect.y);
    }
    else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        rect.setLocation(rect.x - 10, rect.y);
    }
    else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        rect.setLocation(rect.x, rect.y - 10);
    }
    else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        rect.setLocation(rect.x, rect.y + 10);
    }


    repaint();
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {


}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {


}


}
```

Here's the code from the YouTube tutorial:

```
package boxHero;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class boxGame2 extends Applet implements KeyListener {

private Rectangle rect;                          // Declaring a rectangle object

private ArrayList<Integer> keysDown;

private int x = 20, y = 20, recW = 50, recH = 50;


public void init() {
    setSize(600, 500);                           // Initial screen size
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);                  // Setting background

    this.addKeyListener(this);                   // Adding KeyListener

    keysDown = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    rect = new Rectangle (x, y, recW, recH);     // Instantiating and Initializing(setting values) for our Rectangle
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

    // Graphics for our rectangle
    g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g2.fill(rect);
}

public void moveRect() {
    int x = rect.x;
    int y = rect.y;

    if(keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_UP)) {
        y -= 10;
    }
    if(keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)) {
        y += 10;
    }
    if(keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)) {
        x -= 10;
    }
    if(keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)) {
        x += 10;
    }

    rect.setLocation(x, y);

    repaint();
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    if(!keysDown.contains(e.getKeyCode()) && e.getKeyCode() != 86) {
        keysDown.add(new Integer(e.getKeyCode()));
    }

    moveRect();


}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    keysDown.remove(e);

}


@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {


}


}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You have posted way to much code in your question, which makes it unclear to us (and to future readers) exactly where the problem is.  Please reduce your problem code to 10 lines or less.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: You might consider switching to use [JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/toc.htm), which is the follow up on `java.awt`. By using the [`Rectangle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Rectangle.html) class and [`KeyEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html) you might creatly simplify your problem's solution. Also consider that *applets* are obsolete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diference between your code and the tutorial is, that the tutorial uses a list of keys that are currently pressed, while you only check out, WHICH key is pressed. 
Make an ArrayList of keys like in the tutorial, then add each key when pressed and remove it, as soon as released. Then you can move your rectangle for every key that is contained in your list.

Answer (score 0):

In your `keyPressed()` event, you add `e.getKeyCode()` to your `keysDown` list. But in your `keyReleased()` event, you only try to remove `e` from your list, which should result in nothing ever getting removed and all keys remaining pressed. So the reason it doesn't move after a few presses is that you are basically pressing left, right, up and down at once, causing them to cancel each other out.

Also, you should make a habit of using `Integer.valueOf(x)` instead of `new Integer(x)`, since it caches values in the range of [-128;127], resulting in much better performance when creating wrappers for values in that range.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Sorry I forgot to reply.